# Ignoring the initialized value in a variable

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

When I run my program, the console is ignoring the first integer input and instead adding 0 to sumOfPositive. For example, after running the program, if the input is: 5, 6, 7, then sumOfPositive will equal 13. But if I change the initial value of sumOfPositive from 0 to say 2, then sumOfPositive will equal 15.

So how do I ignored the initialized value of sumOfPositive and only work with what's captured from the input?

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);     

    int sumOfPositive = 0;
    int sumOfOdd = 0;
    int minInt = 0;
    int numberOfInts = 0;
    int eachIntEntered = myScanner.nextInt();


    while (eachIntEntered != 0) {
        // if the number entered is not 0, assign it to numberOfInt

        eachIntEntered = myScanner.nextInt();

        // if the number entered does not equal 0, add one to numberOfInt
        // if the number entered is positive, add the number to sumOfPositive

        if (eachIntEntered > 0 ) {
        numberOfInts++;
        sumOfPositive += eachIntEntered;

        } 
        // if the number entered is odd, add the number to sumOfOdd

        if (eachIntEntered % 2 != 0) {
            sumOfOdd += eachIntEntered;
        }
        if (eachIntEntered < minInt) {
            minInt = eachIntEntered;
        }

    } // end of while loop

    System.out.println("The minimum integer is " + minInt);
    System.out.println("The sum of the positive integers is " + sumOfPositive);
    System.out.println("The sum of the odd integers is " + sumOfOdd);
    System.out.println("The count of the positive integers in the sequence is " + numberOfInts);

} // end of main function


} // end of class
```

Comment: The first number gets read before the loop. The computer is doing exactly what you told it.

Comment: What do you mean with `ignored the initialized value of sumOfPositive and only work with what's captured from the input?`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting two inputs back to back, but ignoring the first value. Outside of your while loop you do `int eachIntEntered = myScanner.nextInt();` and feed it a value, then in the while loop you do `eachIntEntered = myScanner.nextInt();` before adding the previous value to `sumOfPositive` or `sumOfOdd`, so you get the behavior that the first value entered is ignored.

One way to fix this is by moving the line `eachIntEntered = myScanner.nextInt();` from the top of your loop to the bottom so that your first run through the loop uses the initial value of `eachIntEntered`:

```
while (eachIntEntered != 0) {   
        // if the number entered does not equal 0, add one to numberOfInt
        // if the number entered is positive, add the number to sumOfPositive

        if (eachIntEntered > 0 ) {
        numberOfInts++;
        sumOfPositive += eachIntEntered;

        } 
        // if the number entered is odd, add the number to sumOfOdd

        if (eachIntEntered % 2 != 0) {
            sumOfOdd += eachIntEntered;
        }
        if (eachIntEntered < minInt) {
            minInt = eachIntEntered;
        }
        // if the number entered is not 0, assign it to numberOfInt

        eachIntEntered = myScanner.nextInt();

    } // end of while loop
```

There is no way to "ignore" the initial value of `sumOfPositive`. You can't add to the variable without knowing what its previous value was. Setting it to zero seems to be the correct behavior for what you want.

Comment: I think your initialization it's not a good practise because it will always enter into the loop (if the value it's `-1`) and maybe the first number that the man types it's `0` but the program will be already inside the loop. The second one it's what I was going to put so it's a good one ;)